# Search item from datatable(cache object) vs database

Tags: c#, asp.net

Current I have a large data that stored inside database.

This set of data (3000 records) will be retrieve by user frequently.

Currently the method that I'm using right now is:

1. Retrieve this set of records from database
2. Convert into datatable
3. Store into a cache object
4. Search result from this cache object base on query

   ```
   CachePostData.Select(string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'", txtItemName.Text));
   ```
5. Bind the result to a repeater (with paging that display 40 records per page)

But I notice that the performance is not good (about 4 seconds on every request). So, I am wondering is there any better way to do this? Or I should straight away retrieve the result from the database for every query?

Comment: How many request/second do you get or expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataTable.Select` is probably not the most efficient way to search an in-memory cache, but it certainly shouldn't take 4 seconds or anything like to search 3000 rows.

First step is to find out where your performance bottlenecks are.  I'm betting it's nothing to do with searching the cache, but you can easily find out, e.g. with code something like:

```
var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var result = CachePostData.Select(string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'", txtItemName.Text));

WriteToLog("Read from cache took {0} ms", stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
```

where `WriteToLog` traces somewhere (e.g. System.Diagnostics.Trace, System.Diagnostics.Debug, or a logging framework such as log4net).

If you are looking for alternatives for caching, you could simply cache a generic list of entity objects, and use Linq to search the list:

```
var result = CachePostData.Select(x => x.Name.Contains(txtItemName.Text));
```

This is probably slightly more efficient (for example, it doesn't need to parse the "NAME LIKE ..." filter expression), but again, I don't expect this is your bottleneck.

Comment: I was wondering the same. The problem has to be somewhat correlated to the query, though, since they claim that it works much faster when they display the data directly without selecting with that like query.

Comment: "...since they claim that it works much faster when they ..." - don't believe such claims without verifying them.  Reproduce the performance problem first, then investigate.

Comment: Yes. You are right. The delay issue come from other part. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think using datatable would be more efficient as by doing that you will reduce the hits on your database server. You can store datatable in cache and then to reuse it. Something like this:-

```
public DataTable myDatatable()
{
   DataTable dt = HttpContext.Current.Cache["key"] as DataTable;
   if(dt == null)
   {
       dt = myDatatable();
       HttpContext.Current.Cache["key"] = dt;
   }
   return dt;
}
```

Also check [SqlCacheDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx)

You may also clear the cache on some particular time interval like this:-

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("key", dt, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(2), 
System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

Also check [DataTable caching performance](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/368962/DataTable-caching-performance)

Comment: I am using this method right now. If display without any search query, the speed is very fast. But when come to search certain record in the datatable, it seems like need some time to complete the request.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit hard to declare a correct solution for your problem without knowing how many hits on the database you actually expect. For most cases, I would not cache the data in the ASP.NET cache for filtering, because searching by using `DataTable.Select` basically performs a table scan and cannot take advantage of database indexing. Unless you run into really heavy load, most database server should be capable of performing this task with less delay than filtering the `DataTable` in .NET.

If your database supports fulltext search (ie. MSSQL or MySQL), you could create a fulltext index on the name column and query that. Fulltext search should give you even faster response types for these types of `LIKE` queries.

Generally, caching data for faster access is good, but in this case, the `DataTable` is most likely inferior to the database server in terms of searching for data. You could still use the cache to display unfiltered data faster and without hitting the database.

Comment: "searching by using DataTable.Select basically performs a table scan and cannot take advantage of database indexing" - but for the filter in question - LIKE that starts with a wildcard - the database would perform a table scan too.

Comment: @Joe One could argue that that is an implemention detail, but yes. :) But from experience, I do think that this should not be a problem in this scenario. Also, letting the server do the query would make a transition to fulltext search a bit easier.